# Get specific elements from Table

Tags: jquery, html-table

I created a table and added a checkbox for each row, I would like to capture the 'PUID' value and the 'ID' value when a user ticks a checkbox.

[image]

This is the result I get:

```
Prod1
AppName1    

a0L2000000Rpc1UEAR
```

But I would like to get something like this:

```
inputText,a0L2000000Rpc1UEAR
```

***JSFiddle***: https://jsfiddle.net/gczr3yxd/1/

JS:

```
 j.each(j("input[name='case[]']:checked").closest("td").siblings("td"), function(index, value) {
            if (index % 4 == 0) { //break line just before a new row
              //values.push('\n');
              counter++;
            }
            values.push(j(this).text());

          });

          values.join('\n');
          values = values.toString();
          values = values.replace(/,/g, '\n');
          console.log(values);
```

Comment: Is this what you want ? https://jsfiddle.net/gczr3yxd/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this code: https://jsfiddle.net/gczr3yxd/4/

```
function getTableRowData(ele) {
    var j = jQuery.noConflict();
    values = new Array();
    counter = 0;
    var vv = new Array();
    j.each(j("input[name='case[]']:checked").closest("td").siblings("td"), function(index, value) {
        if (index % 4 == 0) { //break line just before a new row
            //values.push('\n');
            counter++;
        }
        ++index;
        var tdhtml = j(this).html();
        if (tdhtml.indexOf('input') != -1) {
            values.push(j(this).find('input').val());
        } else if (index % 4 == 0) {
            values.push(j(this).text());
        }
        if (index % 4 == 0 && index > 0) {    
          vv.push(values.join(','));
          values = new Array();
        }
    });
    var data2 = vv.join('\n');

    console.log(data2);
}
```

First, increased **index** so we get proper value when applying modulo(%). As per condition, values are added to the array and join by a comma at every fourth loop and added to an array and at the end join the final array.

Comment: Thanks @Bhumi Shah, it works for one checkbox but if I mark more than one then it does not work.

Comment: Thanks man, it works! Would you mind adding some explanations to your solution before I mark it as the accepted answer?

Comment: Yes, explained little bit so get idea what i have done!!